# How to include only specific module in nestjs swagger

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
app.enableCors();
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

const config = new DocumentBuilder()
               .setTitle('API')
               .setDescription('Node Api to connec')
               .setVersion('1.0.0')
               .build();
const document = `SwaggerModule.createDocument`(app, config);
SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

await app.listen(8000);
```

I have some modules like user module(UserModule), driver module(DriverModule).
I only want driver module's api to be shown in swagger.

I know `SwaggerModule.createDocument` have third parameter for SwaggerOption.

```
const option:SwaggerDocumentOptions = {
 include: [() => DriversModule],
 deepScanRoutes: true
}
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config, option);
```

But after writing like this Swagger is not showing any api. I am getting `No operations defined in spec!` message from swagger in UI.
I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

```
const option:SwaggerDocumentOptions = {
  include: [() => DriversModule],
  deepScanRoutes: true
}
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config, option);
```

The problem was in include property. I was giving a function which return module. When I wrote module directly then it works.

```
const option:SwaggerDocumentOptions = {
  include: [DriversModule],
  deepScanRoutes: true
}
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config, option);
```

This will work.